# why does global variables in python function works different in different scenarios?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

```
myGlobal = 5
z=2
def func1(a):
    a=1
```

> ```
> def func2(a):
>     a=1
>     myGlobal=z+1   # here it doesnt throw any error
>     print (myGlobal)
> ```

```
func1(z)
func2(z)

myGlobal = 5
z=2
def func1(a):
    a=1


def func2(a):
    a=1
    z=z+1   # here it throws any error stating local variable is not defined
    print (myGlobal)

func1(z)
func2(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are trying to reassign to the same variable name so python will consider z as now local scope since its being modified inside the function without being declared as global. you can use `dis` to see whats happening under the hood here. In func1 you can see `z` is loaded from global but in the second func due to the syntax it thinks you referencing the local value of z so its loaded from the local scope where z doesnt exist.

```py
myGlobal = 5
z=2
def func1(a):
    a=z+1


def func2(a):
    z=z+1   # here it throws any error stating local variable is not defined

from dis import dis
print(dis(func1))
print("###")
print(dis(func2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (z)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
None
###
  9           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (z)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (z)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Comment: thanks , but is there any reason for this  behavior ?

Comment: yes, python doesn't allow ambiguity when it comes to variable names and scope; a variable cannot be local scope and global scope inside the same function. Since there is an assign statement to `z` in the function and no reference to `global z` then python decides that z is local scope. so when you do z=z+1, python will look up z in the local scope which doesn't exist hence the referenced before error message

Comment: but instead of z=z+1 , if I put myGlobal=z+1 ,                                                      myglobal being global variable it works fine and i havent referenced z to global here

Comment: no myGlobal will also be considered a local variable here not global, if you try printing myGlobal in the function and then outside the funtion you will see you didnt actually change the global version of myGlobal

Comment: mayber have a read of this https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php

Comment: ok u r saying in an expression a variable(z in z=z+1) cannot have both local and global scope

Comment: yeah you cant have z on the left hand side of the expression as local scope and z on the right hand side of the expression as global scope